# Newline character omitted while reading from buffer

Tags: java, bufferedreader, linefeed

I've written the following code:

```
public class WriteToCharBuffer {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String text = "This is the data to write in buffer!\nThis is the second line\nThis is the third line";
  OutputStream buffer = writeToCharBuffer(text);
  readFromCharBuffer(buffer);
 }

 public static OutputStream writeToCharBuffer(String dataToWrite){
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(byteArrayOutputStream));
  try {
   bufferedWriter.write(dataToWrite);
   bufferedWriter.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return byteArrayOutputStream;
 }

 public static void readFromCharBuffer(OutputStream buffer){
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) buffer;
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())));
  String line = null;
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  try {
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    //System.out.println(line);
    sb.append(line);
   }
   System.out.println(sb);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
}
```

When I execute the above code, following is the output:

```
This is the data to write in buffer!This is the second lineThis is the third line
```

Why are the newline characters (\n) skipped? If I uncomment the **System.out.println()** as following:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        sb.append(line);
       }
```

I get the correct output as:

```
This is the data to write in buffer!
This is the second line
This is the third line
This is the data to write in buffer!This is the second lineThis is the third line
```

What is reason for this?

Comment: Uncommenting `System.out.println(line);` doesn't give the correct output , cos `System.out.println prints` a string with a newline. Try replacing it with `System.out.print(line);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) Says

```
public String readLine()
                throws IOException
```

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>   **Returns:**
>   A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters,   or null if the end of the stream has been reached
>   Throws:

Comment: @jigar, Do you know any reader which can read line along with the new line character?

Comment: @Elliot you can read char by char [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--)

Answer (score 9):

From [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed **('\n')**, a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

You can do something like that

```
buffer.append(line);
buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone wants to read the text with `'\n'` included.

try this **simple approach**

So,

Say, You have **three lines** of data (say in a `.txt` file) , like this

```
This is the data to write in buffer!
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

And **while reading**, you are doing something like this

```
    String content=null;
    String str=null;
    while((str=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){ //assuming you have 
    content.append(str);                     //your bufferedReader declared.
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    System.out.println(content);
```

and **expecting the output** to be

```
This is the data to write in buffer!
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

**but scratching your head upon seeing output** as a single line

```
This is the data to write in buffer!This is the second lineThis is the third line
```

**Here is what you can do**

by adding this piece of code inside your while loop

```
if(str.trim().length()==0){
   content.append("\n");
}
```

So now what your `while` loop should look like

```
while((str=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    if(str.trim().length()==0){
       content.append("\n");
    }
    content.append(str);
}
```

Now you get required output (as three lines of text)

```
This is the data to write in buffer!
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the javadocs says for the readLine() method of class BufferedReader

```
 /**
 * Reads a line of text.  A line is considered to be terminated by any one
 * of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
 * followed immediately by a linefeed.
 *
 * @return     A String containing the contents of the line, not including
 *             any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
 *             stream has been reached
 *
 * @exception  IOException  If an I/O error occurs
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

`readline()` does not return the platforms line ending. [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of readLine(). From [Java Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> Read a line of text. A line is
> considered to be terminated by any one
> of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage
> return ('\r'), or a carriage return
> followed immediately by a linefeed.

So what is happening is your "\n" are being considered as a line feed so reader considers that to be a line.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue from a ByteArrayInputStream where the file contents are loaded as a byte array from the database and that's being read through IOUtils.readlines().

The issue that I faced is due to the backslash character '\' that's being read as a separate character from the newline character '\n', so it returns the entire content as a single line. An example file record as below.

"Header\\nRow1\\nRow2"

I had to write a separate code to replace the characters from '\\n' to '\n' by converting the byte array into string for the string replacements and again converted back to byte array from the newly formed string and that worked for me.