# keeping newline characters when writing a file

Tags: java, newline

I´m exporting data from a database table and writing it down in a file. Newline characters are correctly retrieved from the database and kept when writing the String (so I´m able to reimport the exported data).

My problem is that in the file the newline characters are implicit (i.e. they appear as line breaks). If the database value is the string "line1 \r\n line2", the result of directly sending this String to my BufferedWriter + FileOutputStream is 
"line1
line2"

Is there any way I can write to the file exactly the "line1 \r\n line2" sequence of characters? (I've already tried bw.write(value.toCharArray())

Comment: Although they appear as line breaks (because that's what they are), the characters are still there.  Programmatically load the file and display it as an array of characters to validate this, if you need the verification.

Comment: I know the information is there (that´s why I can reimport the data in the database) but I´d like to be able to tell Java not to interpret them and just print them as part of the String as if they were normal characters (and just let the database to reinterpret them when importing the file). Otherwise the file gets too long

Comment: You can find your answer here :[Newline character omitted while reading from buffer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825263/newline-character-omitted-while-reading-from-buffer

Comment: You'll need to do a `replaceAll` of every escape character, and escape its backslash.  One example: `str.replaceAll("\n", "\\n")`.

Comment: You're right, this should work. You may want to add this as answer instead of a comment so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: Alright, give me a minute.  I'll make it a complete answer too, handling all escape characters.

Comment: My apologies for taking so long, I had some other obligations to attend to.  Anyway, I've written the method in the most concise way I could think of, and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace every escape sequence with a double-backslash:

```
public static String escapeChars(String str) {
    char[][] escapes = {
            { '\n', 'n' },
            { '\r', 'r' },
            { '\f', 'f' },
            { '\b', 'b' },
            { '\t', 't' }
    };
    for (char[] escape : escapes) {
        str = str.replaceAll(Character.toString(escape[0]), "\\\\" + escape[1]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Double- and single-apostrophe escaping can be added easily, but I've omitted it in this answer.