# Write a string in a file exactly how it is

Tags: java, string, file

How is possible to write a string in a file .txt exactly how it is?

For example, I want to write exactly the following string :

> Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow
>
> and I'm asking a question

I tried with BufferedWriter, PrintWriter, PrintStream, but the result is always the same, so in my file .txt the string appears like this :

> Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow  and I'm asking a question

It is necessary to analyze each character or is there an easier way?

Comment: you want it in 2 lines?

Comment: You said you tried `BufferedWriter`, `PrintWriter`, `PrintStream`. What went wrong? Can you show us some code?

Comment: if new lines are your problem look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696889/keeping-newline-characters-when-writing-a-file

Comment: Did you try using `println` with any of those?

Comment: @Trudbert the question you refer is not the same thing, because I want to write the string exactly how it is, I'm not intrested to keep characters. I don't know if you got it.

Answer (score 2):

Use any one

- [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)  to a new line after adding first message
- [`PrintWriter#println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29) method to add a new line

Sample code: (Try any one)

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt"))) {
    writer.write("Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow");
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("and I'm asking a question");
}

try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt"))) {
    writer.write("Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow");
    writer.println();
    writer.write("and I'm asking a question");
}

try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("abc.txt")) {
    writer.write("Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow");
    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
    writer.write("and I'm asking a question");
}
```

Read more about [Java 7 The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handle the resources carefully.

Comment: can you provide a short example? I didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the line breaks.

If you use `PrintWriter.println()` the platform specific line separator is used: `"\r\n"` on Windows.

Windows Notepad will not handle `"\n"` but WordPad does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `newLine()` method of [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) class.

> A newLine() method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion
>   of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator.
>   Not all platforms use the newline character ('\n') to terminate lines.
>   Calling this method to terminate each output line is therefore
>   preferred to writing a newline character directly.

You may try like this using \n as well:

```
String s ="Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow\n"
          +"and I'm asking a question";
```

or

```
String s = String.format("%s\n%s","Hello, I'm an user of stackoverflow",
              "and I'm asking a question");
```

Comment: The string is given, so how can I know when it's time to start a new line?

Comment: @Fabrizio:- Updated the answer using a simple \n!